# Sitecore converting Lucene configuration to Solr configuration

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore8.2

Below is my configurations which I am using with Lucene Search engine now I want to change this for Solr, for this what are the changes required I'm not sure

Below is my configuration

```
 <contentSearch>
  <indexConfigurations>
    <defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
      <mediaIndexing>
        <mimeTypes>
          <includes patch:instead="includes" />
        </mimeTypes>
        <extensions>
          <includes patch:instead="includes" />
        </extensions>
      </mediaIndexing>
    </defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
    <MyLibraryresponsiveSearchConfiguration
      type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
      <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>
      <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd>
      <analyzer ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/analyzer" />
      <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
          <field fieldName="hide in search" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f"
                 type="System.Boolean"
                 settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <field fieldName="publishing date" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f"
                 type="System.DateTime"
                 settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <analyzer
              type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          </field>

        </fieldNames>
      </fieldMap>
      <fieldReaders ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/fieldReaders" />
      <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter
        ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/indexFieldStorageValueFormatter" />
      <indexDocumentPropertyMapper
        ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/indexDocumentPropertyMapper" />
      <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
        <field fieldName="search_content" storageType="no" indexType="tokenized">MyLibrary.Core.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.SearchContentField, MyLibrary.Core</field>
        <field fieldName="search_content" storageType="no" indexType="tokenized">MyLibrary.Core.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.VisualizationField, MyLibrary.Core</field>
        <field fieldName="webinar session 1 time zone" storageType="YES" indexType="tokenized">MyLibrary.Core.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.WebinarTimeZoneField, MyLibrary.Core</field>
        <field fieldName="webinar session 2 time zone" storageType="YES" indexType="tokenized">MyLibrary.Core.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.WebinarTimeZoneField, MyLibrary.Core</field>
        <field fieldName="webinar session 1 date time" storageType="YES" indexType="tokenized">MyLibrary.Core.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.WebinarDateTimeField, MyLibrary.Core</field>
        <field fieldName="webinar session 2 date time" storageType="YES" indexType="tokenized">MyLibrary.Core.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.WebinarDateTimeField, MyLibrary.Core</field>
        <field fieldName="publishing year" storageType="YES" indexType="tokenized">MyLibrary.Core.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.PublishingYearField, MyLibrary.Core</field>
      </fields>
    </MyLibraryresponsiveSearchConfiguration> 
  </indexConfigurations>
</contentSearch>
```

I am getting this error

> Could not find configuration node:
>   contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/analyzer